# How to properly add an alias in SQL Server Configuration Manager for Local Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022, sql-server-config-manager

The application in the configuration has the given name (localdb)/MyProj. I do not want to change the application code to connect to the server, so for this purpose I wanted to use the aliasing functionality available in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In SQL Server Configuration Manager:
In Client Protocols I set TCP/IP and Named Pipes to Enabled.
In aliases, I added two new aliases.
Alias name: (localdb)/MyProj
Port No: 1433
Protocol: TCP/IP
Server: MyServer

and another with a different name: MyProj

In Protocols for MSSQLSERVER > TCP/IP > I have TCP Port 1433 set.
I checked with cmd netstat -an if the port is listening, it is.
I restarted the service and the machine.
SELECT @@SERVERNAME returns MyServer

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio with MyServer or MyServer,1433 or using ip I can connect to the server.

However, none of the prepared aliases work.
What else should I check or change to use an alias?

Comment: You set the aliases on the client computer, not the server, right?  Can the client connect using MyServer, or MyServer,1433?

Comment: Have you genericized the name by calling it `(localdb)` or is it actually `(localdb)`? Sounds like an application-managed LocalDB instance - and you shouldn't be able to connect to that using SSMS.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning In the application I have given the name (localdb)/MyProj. Only MyProj is changed. That's why I created two aliases to test their operation also in SSMS.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The server and the application are on a local machine. I also set the aliases on the local machine.